# Controller X new from Controller Y form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails, is it possible to have a form on the 'show' action of Controller X and upon submission call the 'new' action for Controller Y that creates a 'new' record associated with Y...?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Simply declare `@y = y.new` in the `show` method in Controller X and create a form in the `show` view of Controller X with `form_for @y`.

This will automatically call the `create` method in Controller Y.